# problema ao popular um controle do tipo option

Tags: vba, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Tenho um codigo VBA mas estou com problemas ao popular um elemento.

Quando tendo colocar dados no controle aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro:

**erro em tempo de execução '2146233079 (80131509)':
unknown error: cannot focus element...**

```
Sub x()
    Dim objCollection
    Dim numeroPregao, dataAssinatura, uasg, item, val, m
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim ULogin As Boolean, ieForm
    Dim MyPass As String, MyLogin As String
    Dim driver As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
    Dim windowHandleJanelaInicial As String

    ctr = 2
    For y = 0 To 13680 'vai de zero ao numero de linhas a ser prenchido
    m = 0
    c3 = 1
    c2 = 1

    driver.Start "chrome", "http://comprasnet.gov.br"
    driver.setImplicitWait 5000
    driver.Open "/acesso.asp?url=/Livre/Ata/ConsultaAta00.asp"

    Set objCollection = driver.findElementByCssSelector("frame[name='main2']")
    driver.SwitchToFrame (objCollection)

    driver.FindElementByName("dt_ini").SendKeys "25/11/2015"
    driver.FindElementByName("dt_fim").SendKeys "24/11/2015"
    driver.FindElementByXPath("//option[text()='<Escolha pelo menos um material ou serviço>']").SendKeys "222345" 'o erro ocorre aqui
```

Comment: Fazendo um debug, onde está dando o erro?

Comment: na ultima linha 'o erro ocorre aqui

Comment: acredito que o xpath identificado está errado...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui contornar meu erro! o problema estava ocorrendo porque o controle que eu estava tentando manipular não estava **"acessível"**.

O jeito foi clicar no botão **"selecionar"** e fazer a interação com os controles do popup **seleção de material**